# Energy consumption when cell phone charger connected to socket but not to phone

Tags: batteries

When my cell phone is charged fully, it says 'Please remove charger from wall socket to save energy'. How am I wasting energy if the charger is connected to the socket but the phone is not connected? I thought you only consume energy when you connect the phone.

Comment: Consumer product support is considered off topic. It seems you already received your answer but there any many sites for discussing things like these such as the android SE, the Apple SE or [SU] depending on the specifics of what you are asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With no phone/device attached to a charger, it is still possible for the charger to consume some energy. How much energy is dependent on what exactly is inside the charger.

The simplest charger could potentially be a transformer and a linear regulator. In this case, the transformer would step down the wall voltage and the linear regulator will pump out a relatively solid voltage to charge your device. In this case, the charger itself is always drawing some energy. A linear regulator converts voltages, say 9V to 5V, and dissipates the rest of the power as heat. As a result linear regulators can be fairly inefficient. The upside however, is that they are generally much cheaper than most alternatives. A simple rule here would be that if the charger is warm to the touch with no phone/device attached, you're wasting energy.

Charger technologies have certainly changed and adapted, especially with the growing concern for being green. As a result, many manufacturers have opted for more energy efficient means of charging devices. The message you receive from your cell phone telling you that it is fully charged is an example. Modern devices are usually smart enough to limit their power consumption once they are fully charged.

All that said, your charger is likely fine to remain plugged in without a device attached. If you want to be sure you can purchase something like the [Kill A Watt](http://www.p3international.com/products/special/p4400/p4400-ce.html) to test your charger. There are also various articles and experiments that have tested this idea out:
[From Slate](http://www.slate.com/articles/health_and_science/the_green_lantern/2009/10/you_charged_me_all_night_long.html) [another site](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CDIQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.powerint.com%2Fen%2Ffaq%2F5&ei=0j2UT9mAD8rz6QHMsZSIBA&usg=AFQjCNE0seoilAa8vxpiDshMYghHkgiMlA) [and another](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&ved=0CEkQFjAD&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.inference.phy.cam.ac.uk%2Fsustainable%2Fcharger%2F&ei=0j2UT9mAD8rz6QHMsZSIBA&usg=AFQjCNEN7YZYSwMjjS0hteDommaRrNw5Zw)

Answer (score 3):

It's similar to how your TV 'off', but somehow is ready to respond to your remote control at a moments notice.  Well, that means something is actually 'on'.  Not a huge something, but something nonetheless.  It's the same for the charger.  There are components to assist with the charging that need to be ready when your phone is plugged it.  A voltage regulator, for instance, to regulate the charge voltage.  Many of these draw power even when doing 'nothing' (they are essentially always powering themselves even if they're powering nothing else). That means the device isn't 'off', but instead in standby - waiting and drawing power. Advances in electronics have helped us limit the amount of power required for these standby modes (it's orders of magnitude less than the amount of power used for charging) but it will never be zero for the simple fact that when you plug in your phone you expect it to start charging.

If you're concerned about this, you can get something like [this](http://www.kk.org/cooltools/archives/003628.php).  Its a power strip with a hard switch for every outlet.  If you don't want your charger to draw power when your phone isn't plugged in just flip the switch off - it will draw zero power.  When you want to charge your phone, plug it in and flip the switch on.  I can pretty much guarantee you you'll forget to flip the switch one night and end up with an uncharged phone in the morning.  At some point the standby from leaving the charger plugged in is worth it.

Answer (score 1):

> When my cell phone is charged fully, it says 'Please remove charger from wall socket to save energy'. How am I wasting energy if the charger is connected to the socket but the phone is not connected? I thought you only consume energy when you connect the phone.

This "feature" has annoyed me for some while as

### the message is liable to be untrue and if followed is liable to incur slight extra cost to the user and to society overall.

This answer is thus more detailed than it might otherwise be as it gives me a chance to 'rail on' about such stupidities :-).

This message indicates 'a lack of capability' and/or 'unclear thinking' on the part of the system designer and also ***may*** be due to ulterior motives that they'd rather not state due to potential liability issues.

It is possible to build a cellphone charger that draws so little power either from the mains or from the cellphone battery as to be wholly irrelevant.
 All that is requred is to monitor the cellphone battery voltage (which is almost always LiIon (Lithium Ion) and detect whether the voltage indicates the battery is fully charged. If necessary the charger could test for full charge say once a minute or even once every two minutes.

**Costs more overall:**  Quick back-of-invisible-envelope calculation suggests that you could do this with a few cents worth of mains electricity per year. Saving that by unplugging the phone would assist the "green" power drive but would also  lead to more losses overall in recharge power efficiency losses and in extra wear on the battery.

Worse still, the phones that I have seen, and possibly most phones that give this message, do so even if the phone is turned on an in receive mode. This means that the power for the receiver, which could be supplied from the mains at low energy cost per unit, is instead supplied by the battery. This adds to battery cycling thus (slightly) reducing battery lifetime, means the phone has slightly less battery capacity available when you next want to use it away from the charger and takes more energy to recharge again that it would have required to leave it plugged in, due to overall charge-discharge energy inefficiencies compared to charger to phone power efficiency.

**Liability:** Anything plugged into mains has SOME possibility of a mains power incident. Worst case outcome is major catastrophe (fire, death, sky falls in), and lesser ones are charger and/or equipment damage or destruction. If the equipment is well designed and well built the chances of **any** this happening are vanishingly small. But, a US law suit avoided is $US5 million earned,so if this can be avoided even a few times a year, so much the better. However, saying "unplug charger and or equipment when not strictly necessary to be connected to minimise chances of the sky falling in" is liable to not sit well with the corporate lawyers or bean counters and may increase the chances of being sued, or class action suits being brought by 'Friends of The Sky', or whoever, whereas "Be green, save truly trivial amounts of energy, unplug our badly designed charger NOW" is liable to win them brownie points. Whether this is part of the reasoning in any given case is outside my ability to tell and I offer this as a wholly hypothetical postulate [tm]. [Corporate lawyers and bean counters for large multinational communication conglomerates please note just prior disclaimer].

Comment: I once had two flyers in my mail: An ad for an "intelligent" switch that turns off devices when they're in standby to save electricity, and another one for an electric heating... What has this society come to?!